# How to pinpoint missing columns when extracting from GTFS using tidytransit in R?

Tags: r, gtfs

I am trying to extract stop-level frequencies from Public Transport Victoria's GTFS in R, using tidytransit. Specifically, I have downloaded GTFS for 1 Mar 2018: https://transitfeeds.com/p/ptv/497/20180301

After successfully reading in and unzipping the GTFS, I am unable to further analyse due to an issue with missing trip_ids.

I would like to know how to identify which tables are missing the trip_id column, and if possible, how to join it in so I can extract stop frequencies.

1. First, I have tried to filter for a date range:

```
install.packages('tidytransit')
library(tidytransit)

gtfs_1Mar<- read_gtfs("gtfs_1Mar18.zip",local=TRUE)

g<-set_date_service_table(gtfs_1Mar)
gtfs_20Mar<-filter_stop_times(g, "2018-03-20","06:00:00","09:00:00")
```

2. Extract stop frequencies

```
get_stop_frequency(gtfs_1Mar, start_hour = 6, end_hour = 22,
                   , dow = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), by_route = False,wide = FALSE)
```

When using command "filter_stop_times" I receive error:

```
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: trip_id
```

A similar error message appears when attempting to use the command get_stop_frequency:

```
Error: `by` can't contain join column `trip_id` which is missing from LHS
```

Comment: Please check your data with the default dataset `gtfs_obj` in `?get_stop_frequency`

Comment: Problem fixed. The particular gtfs  I am using contains some erroneous column headers, which I now clearly see by inspecting the elements contained in gtfs_obj.

Comment: Errors in GTFS are more than common, especially in headers. Currently working on a project using GTFS, I ended up implementing a home made GTFS parser/correcter/rewriter after realizing that almost every single existing feed comes up with a new way not to respect the specification.